# Why does a double quote not work for a regex pattern match in Rails 4.2.6 text_field_tag?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am rendering a form via the *form_tag* helper in ActiveAdmin along with a text field via *text_field_tag*.  I use a pattern restriction to ensure only strings of the form "MMMYYYY" (e.g., JUL2022 or AUG2023) can be submitted.

```
<%= text_field_tag(:myear, nil, placeholder: "JUL2020", pattern: '^[A-Z]{3}\d{4}$') %>
```

If I put the pattern in double quotes, instead of single quotes, I get a "Please match the requested format error".  Why does the type of quote string matter?

Answer (score 0):

From the ruby-doc

> quote(str): 
>   Escapes any characters that would have special meaning in a regular expression. Returns a new escaped string, or self if no characters are escaped.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-quote

This use of single quotes for escaping patterns in regular expressions has been around for a while now (I can't tell you how the convention first came about).